# Replacing slow to switch Presta/Schrader pump head with dual pump head on a floor pump. Can I go between brands?

Tags: maintenance, pump, preventative-maintenance

I have a Giyo Air Supply floor pump which has one of those Presta/Schrader switchable heads where you have to unscrew the cap, wiggle out the head's innards for half an hour, turn them around then screw the cap back on to switch to the other valve type. Henceforth reffered to as the **lame head.** No matter how much I lubricate the rubber gasket, or use a screw to pry it out, it always takes way too long. It's also old, the plastic piece that pushes on the Schrader valve is almost broken.

So the other day in a Decathlon I grabbed a replacement **dual head,** hoping to upgrade the lame head. The label says this dual head is built for B'Twin 100 / 500 / 900 floor pumps. To be clear, what I have is from another brand. Could it work?

I used calipers to measure the diameter of the rubber tube – 10mm – and the diameter of the plastic nut on the new head, that has to go over it – 10.6mm. Seems compatible.

The lame head does have a nut with thread on it, so it seems designed to be replaceable. But I can't tell if the tube is sealed on by press fit or with some adhesive.

The problem is I don't want to remove the working lame head and not be able to put it back. **Is it reasonable to try to remove the lame head** and assume there's not any adhesive seal or any other planned obsolescence gotchas?

Comment: I replaced a head with one form a different brand no problems, however as the original was broken (driven over by a car), I had nothing to lose trying.

Comment: I found a lot of useful pump head options on aliexpress - the cheapest $3 ones are to be avoided but I got an excellent one for around $15 and that had a 5 foot hose too, which makes any track pump much more useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly it seems like a low-stakes experiment 8) It should be no problem as long as the hose has a similar inner and outer diameter, which is likely.

If it's hard to disassemble the old pump head, you can just cut it off, if you can get a reasonably square cut.

I've never encountered adhesive seals, it's usually a barb on which the hose is pushed plus an o-ring and  a large nut that compresses the whole assembly.

Comment: This one does seem to have an adhesive seal. I pulled on it a lot and it wouldn't budge even a little bit.

Comment: Cut it off with garden shears or sharp and large scissors.